# Why is IOS Playground returning error invalid context CGContextSaveGState?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have a fresh new-playground project and does not display anything in the assistant window, however, the source appears to be interpreted.  The implication from the error (see below) is to set an environment variable.  I don't know how to create this setting (or what to set it to).

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import XCPlayground
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"
```

Console output:

```
Oct 16 18:07:45  MyPlayground[76581] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct 16 18:07:45  MyPlayground[76581] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct 16 18:07:45  MyPlayground[76581] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Comment: Is that the full source of your playground?  You don't have any CoreGraphics calls in there, nothing that takes a CGContextRef as an argument?

Comment: That is literally my code.